# Display DialogFragment without blocking the views(clicks) beneath it?

Tags: android, dialog

```
    getDialog().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
    getDialog().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
    getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

I'm trying to display a simple dialog that looks like so:

[image]

and then it will auto dismiss after one second or on tap.. however, it seems, of course like Dialogs should/do, disable the UI thread beneath it, defeating the point of it trying to be unobtrusive.

```
getDialog().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
```

Seems to almost get me there, and makes the buttons i have ON listview items clickable, but their listview item parent not?

Comment: Just implement your `Dialog` as a normal layout(centered) which you add to your current layout(which will have to be one of the `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout`).